# Difference in Diagonal Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a board of size 4x4:

```
board=[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]

board = [1,0,0,0]
        [0,1,0,0]
        [0,0,1,0]
        [0,0,0,1]

board2= [0,0,1,0]
        [1,0,0,0]
        [0,0,1,0]
        [1,0,0,0]
```

I have to do a diagonal check on this board i.e. if the elements are diagonal to each other it should return False, else True.

I thought of getting the co-ordinates of the elements with the value '1' in them but couldn't think of a logic to implement the rest.

```
def diagonal(trialboard):
    coordinates=[]
    for i in range(0,len(trialboard)):
        for j in range(0 ,len(trialboard)):
            if trialboard[i][j]==1:
                a=[i,j]
                coordinates.append(a)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you expect? And the board will change? Not quite understand your question

Comment: KInd of confusing. A function called diagonal returns False if it is diagonal, or True if its not diagonal. Is that right?

Comment: What should "elements are diagonal to each other" mean? Do you mean a symmetric matrix?

Comment: @atline  ..sorry for the misunderstanding. I need to find the abs difference between the diagonal elements, if diff==0, return False, else True.

Comment: yeah. @MichaelButscher

Comment: @ChrisCharley I need to find the abs difference between the diagonal elements, if diff==0, return False, else True.

Comment: You can only calculate an absolute difference between two items. Do you mean the difference of minimum and maximum of absolute value of the diagonal items?

Comment: The matrix will only contains 0's and 1's .So for example if there are 1's which are in diagonal to each other, return False, else True.

Comment: If diagonal element is `1 0 0 1`, what output you expect? `[True, False, True]`? A list has 3 elements? Which element compared with which element?

Comment: @atline 1001 can't be a diagonal in the board. check my post for board2, none of the elements are in a diagonal. Hence the function would return True after checking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if I got what you meant

> I have to do a diagonal check on this board i.e. if the elements are diagonal to each other it should return False, else True.

If I am not wrong, then you can check for it to be diagonal with the i-th element of the i-th sublist that should be 1. See:

`board=[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]`

then

```
def diagonal(trialboard): #I assume trialboard is the list such as "board"...
  if len(trialboard[0])!=len(trialboard) return true #if the matrix is not  
                                                     #square it cannot have a
                                                     #diagonal
   #Here I also assume the sublists all have the same length, but this is just
   #for demonstration

  for i in range(0,len(trialboard)):
       if (trialboard[i][i] !=1) : return true  #is not diagonal (as you specified, 
                                                #returns true)
       if (i==len(trialboard)-1) : return false #it didn't fail until the last element,
                                                #then it is 
                                                #diagonal.
```

This also a more efficient approach as you don't need to iterate over every single [i][j] pair as in two nested for statements. You just check the diagonal values.